# Is it possible for Python to read non-ascii text from file?

Tags: python, ascii, decode

I have a .txt file that is UTF-8 formatted and have problems to read it into Python. I have a large number of files and a conversion would be cumbersome.

So if I read the file in via

```
for line in file_obj:
    ...
```

I get the following error:

```
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
    return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 291: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I guess `x.decode("utf-8")` wouldn't work since the error occurs before the line is even read in.

Comment: You can use python 3+ which should work on unicode natively.

Comment: @Serdalis: He _is_ using Python 3. Look at the traceback.

Comment: @abarnert missed that, sorry.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two choices.

1. Specify the encoding when opening the file, instead of using the default.
2. Open the file in binary mode, and explicitly `decode` from `bytes` to `str`.

The first is obviously the simpler one. You don't show how you're opening the file, but assuming your code looks like this:

```
with open(path) as file_obj:
    for line in file_obj:
```

Do this:

```
with open(path, encoding='utf-8') as file_obj:
    for line in file_obj:
```

That's it.

As [the docs](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) explain, if you don't specify an encoding in text mode:

> The default encoding is platform dependent (whatever `locale.getpreferredencoding()` returns), but any encoding supported by Python can be used.

In some cases (e.g., any OS X, or linux with an appropriate configuration), `locale.getpreferredencoding()` will always be 'UTF-8'. But it'll obviously never be "automatically whatever's right for any file I might open". So if you know a file is UTF-8, you should specify it explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

For Python 2 and 3 solution, use codecs:

```
import codecs
file_obj = codecs.open('ur file', "r", "utf-8")

for line in file_obj:
    ...
```

Otherwise -- Python 3 -- use abarnert's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15512760/298607)

Comment: Why use `codecs` when just plain old `open` does the exact same thing?

Comment: @abarnert: Works on both Py 2 and Py 3 I suppose

Comment: Actually, it's not _exactly_ the same. `codecs` does its newline stuff _before_ decoding, while `io.TextIOWrapper` (which is what `open` returns) does it after. So, universal newlines basically don't work right with `codecs.open`. Which is at least part of the reason `codecs.open` hasn't been deprecated—because there's code out there that depends on broken universal newlines. (Still, the idea to deprecate it comes up at least once/year…)